# SQL deleting irrelevant columns

Tags: sql

I am learning SQL right now and i want to do it better then i did so far.
I have 2 Tables.

borders   (**id**, country1, country2, lenght),
country   (**name**, population)

.

I want to get all countrys around a certain country named D.

My solution:

```
SELECT country1, country2 FROM borders WHERE country1 = 'D' OR country2= 'D'
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pax98.png)

But i do not want to get 2 columns.  Is there any option to just get one?
Thanks for any help.

Painter21

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data and desired results.

Comment: which dbms are you on?

Comment: I think you want to say irrelevant instead of inefficient.

Comment: Step 1 - decide which one you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IF`:

```
SELECT IF(country1 = 'D', country2, country1) 
FROM borders 
WHERE 'D' IN (country1, country2)
```

If you are not using MySQL, then a `CASE` expression will do:

```
SELECT CASE country1 WHEN 'D' THEN country2 ELSE country1 END AS country
FROM borders 
WHERE 'D' IN (country1, country2)
```

Comment: IF might not be available on the dbms the OP is using, CASE is probably a  more universal solution

Comment: @vc74 Yes you are right, I thought the question was tagged with MySQL.